# What is DPRTY in z/OS JCL?

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

When we submit a job, the following steps are executed sequentially.

Then what is the importance of DPRTY?

Answer (score 7):

`DPRTY` is a very old JCL keyword that harks back to the days of MVS/ESA. It was the dispatch priority which dictated to JES what priority individual steps should be given in a job.

On all versions of z/OS I have access to (all the supported ones), it has no effect.  This is because the WLM (workload manager) goal mode is the only mode used in z/OS 1.3 and beyond. I believe this keyword was deprecated in MVS/ESA V5R1M0 (see INFO APAR II09592).

You can safely ignore it, since JES itself ignores it - all your job steps will be executed in a top-down manner in your JCL job card, with the dispatch priority given by the `IEAIPSxx` PARMLIB member.

Answer (score 0):

`DPRTY` is used to assign dispatching priority to the job step. It is different from the class priority, as class priority applies for the entire job whereas `DPRTY` applies to particular job step.

## Syntax:

`DPRTY(value1, value2) value1 = 0-15 value2 = 0-15`

`DPRTY` is computed as

`DPRTY = (value1*16) + value2`